# Implementing 1D self attention in PyTorch

Tags: pytorch, attention-model, self-attention

I'm trying to implement the 1D self-attention block below using `PyTorch`:

[image]

proposed in the following [paper](https://easychair.org/publications/preprint/WWf8). Below you can find my (provisional) attempt:

```
import torch.nn as nn
import torch

#INPUT shape ((B), CH, H, W)


class Self_Attention1D(nn.Module):
    
    def __init__(self, in_channels=1, out_channels=3):
        
        super().__init__()
        
        self.pointwise_conv1 = nn.Conv1d(in_channels=in_channels, out_channels=out_channels, kernel_size=(1,1))
        
        self.pointwise_conv2 = nn.Conv1d(in_channels=out_channels, out_channels=in_channels, kernel_size=(1,1))
        
        self.phi = MLP(in_size = out_channels, out_size=32)
        
        self.psi = MLP(in_size = out_channels, out_size=32)
                
        self.gamma = MLP(in_size=32, out_size=out_channels)
                
    def forward(self, x):
                
        x = self.pointwise_conv1(x)
        
        phi = self.phi(x.transpose(1,3))
        
        psi = self.psi(x.transpose(1,3))
        
        delta = phi-psi
        
        gamma = self.gamma(delta).transpose(3,1)
        
        out = self.pointwise_conv2(torch.mul(gamma,x))
        
        return out



class MLP(nn.Module):
    
    def __init__(self, in_size, out_size):
        
        super().__init__()
        
        self.in_size = in_size
        self.out_size = out_size
        
        self.layers = nn.Sequential(
            
            nn.Linear(in_size, 64),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(64,128),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(128,64),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(64,out_size))
    
    def forward(self, x):
        
        out = self.layers(x)
        
        return out
```

I'm not sure at all that this is correct, as the operations in my implementation are happening *globally* while as displayed in the image we should compute some operation between each entry and its neighbours one at a time. I was initially tempted to instantiate a for loop to iteratively compute the neural networks `delta,phi,psi` for each entry, but I felt that it wasn't the right way to do that.

Apologies if this is trivial but I still don't have a huge experience in `PyTorch`.

Comment: It looks like the input with shape `(1,w,c)` is being sliced at the second dimension into green, red, blue. It is not clear from the picture what the gamma symbol "Mapping Function" is doing. The part going from the Self Attention Map to Generated SAM is also a bit unclear. Also as sidenote, pointwise convs can be computed with a normal linear layer: https://github.com/facebookresearch/ConvNeXt/blob/main/models/convnext.py#L30

Comment: The gamma function is simply projecting the result into the same channel space as the pointwise conv in order to perform the Hadamard product. What it’s not clear to me is, how can we implement the boxed operation in such a way that the delta function takes each single entry **and** its neighbour *one at a time*. Because again, I think that my implementation is ignoring this *local* operation.